# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' C# class

Tags: c#

I'm trying make a program where you call operations like addition from classes.

I don't know why there's an error:

```
public string Add() {
    string AdditionTotal;
    int num1 = int.Parse(txtFirstNumber.Text);
    int num2 = int.Parse(txtSecondNumber.Text);
    AdditionTotal = num1 + num2; //throws an error here           
    return AdditionTotal;
}

public string SetText {
    get {
        return txtFirstNumber.Text;
    }
    set {
        txtFirstNumber.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Try like this

```
AdditionTotal = (num1 + num2).ToString();
```

`num1` and `num2` both is an `int` and their sum is also an `int`

`C#` can't convert it directly from `int` to `string` .

you have to cast it pragmatically in order to assign.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `int + int` is an `int` and you are trying to assign it to a `string` variable.

`AdditionTotal` should be an `int` and return type of method an `int`, or return `AdditionTotal.ToString()`

```
public int Add(int Total) {
    int AdditionTotal;
    int num1 = int.Parse(txtFirstNumber.Text);
    int num2 = int.Parse(txtSecondNumber.Text);
    AdditionTotal = num1 + num2; //throws an error here

    return AdditionTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AdditionTotal` is of type of `string` and you are assigning `int` to it. Make `AdditionTotal` an `int` and return `AdditionTotal.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

AB= (A + B).ToString();
Resulted AB will store the sum of A and B (int) and convert it to string. AB will have sum of a and b but in string format like  a=2,b=3 then AB="5".